# How to disable proxy in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, proxy

How to disable the proxy completely? All my applications try to connect through a proxy. I checked the environment. The command `env | grep proxy` did not show anything. All installed applications automatically configure themselves under a proxy.

Comment: If i run comands with `sudo`, they doesn't try to use proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get it. "global" proxies are disabled by clicking the appropriate button in the network settings window, and google drive in nautilus (I wrote this question because of it) did not work because of the expiration of the network account in settings.

Comment: You could inspect at `/etc/apt/apt.conf` what is written, if System settings > network doesn't apply to wide systems, such as `apt`. To disable proxy, empty this file